# WiX 3.7 and MATLAB 2012a MCR

Tags: matlab, wix, windows-installer

Is there tutorial for creating a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) installer, that can check if MCR is already installed and if not can install it?

I'm working with [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012).

Comment: "Matlabn 2012a MCR" is way too specific for their to be a tutorial about installing it.   You will find tutorials on using "Burn" Windows Installer XML's "Bootstrapper/Chainer".

Comment: @ChristopherPainter is it the same as, let's say installing .net 4.5 ? as far as the WIX installer?

Comment: The principals are the same.  The details are different in terms of file name to kick off, command line args to pass, and registry/files to search for to determine if it's already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution for MCR 2012a and .NET 4.5 please comment if there is a better way to do it:
this is for documentation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:netfx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension'>

    <Bundle Name="MYAPP"
            Version="0.6"
            Manufacturer="MY Corporation"
            UpgradeCode="f380ae43-5df1-4cfe-9297-526e3e638e57">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <PackageGroupRef
                Id="Netfx45FullPackage"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
        <util:RegistrySearch
            Id="MatlabPath"
            Variable="UniqueId"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Matworks\MATLAB\4.17\"
            Result="exists"/>
        <PackageGroup Id="Netfx45FullPackage">
            <ExePackage
                Id="Netfx45Xxx"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="no"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="no"
                InstallCommand="/q"
                SourceFile="..\SetupProject\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe"
                DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))"
                InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot; OR Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))"/>
            <ExePackage
                Id="MatlabMCR2012a64"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="no"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="no" 
                InstallCommand="/q"
                SourceFile="..\SetupProject\MCR_R2012a_win64_installer.exe"
                InstallCondition="(NOT MatlabPath)"/>
        <MsiPackage
            Id="MYAPP"
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            Vital="yes"
            SourceFile="..\SetupProject\bin\Release\MYAPPSetup.msi"/>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```